# Android Studio xml ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Layout Preview issue for Android Studio 2.3

I do not know what the problem is.

Is there a solution to this?

=== configuration start ===

os: mac 10.12.3

ide: version: 2.3

compileSdkVersion: 25

buildToolsVersion: 25.0.2

supportLibraryVersion: 25.3.0

=== configuration end ===

=== error report start ===

```
17356
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17356
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2322)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.getAttributes(ClassReader.java:2200)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:565)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.convertClass(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClass(RenderClassLoader.java:148)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFile(RenderClassLoader.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFile(ModuleClassLoader.java:380)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModule(ModuleClassLoader.java:280)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ModuleClassLoader.java:239)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:127)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:222)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:1867)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.parseClass(ViewLoader.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClass(ViewLoader.java:647)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClassSilently(ViewLoader.java:581)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadAndParseRClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:682)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.<init>(RenderTask.java:178)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:241)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.inflate(NlModel.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel.render(NlModel.java:554)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.model.NlModel$3.run(NlModel.java:599)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:260)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:274)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:229)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:378)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:389)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.runFirstTaskThenPollAndRunRest(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:178)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$000(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:40)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:197)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

=== Layout XML ===

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent”>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, try to find out which class is generating the error and then submit for us a piece of your code. The logcat you put doesn't seem to point to your problematic class, look at it, every **at** beginning each line points to a system class, not one made by you. Sorry if I am wrong. Best.

Comment: I've usually seen this when there are issues in the layout XML.  If this were happening to me, I would look at my views first.

Comment: @chrisg
There is no problem with xml.
Because it worked fine before updating the Android studio.

Comment: @statosdotcom
This is not a problem with the Java source code.
This is simply an error in the Layout Preview.

Comment: **Because it worked fine before updating the Android studio** (you could say it before...) Maybe you are using a special component at your layout, a custom view, for example, or a custom combo box, and did not get the correct reference at your build module file, or, after your AS upgrade, some library can get outdated, so review this.

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the caches?  `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Comment: This  issue was already mentioned last year but still no update on that :
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206181

Comment: Can you please provide your XML code here on question ???

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat
To meet your request
I put a very simple xml code.

Comment: @chrisg
Thanks chirs g,
I tried, but it is the same.

Comment: @statosdotcom
The explanation was insufficient due to the lack of English.
I am sorry.
I will review your advice.

Comment: Try using Coordinator layout parent of Appbar layout instead of relativelayout and please  put actual working xml  all syntax are wrong so I am not able to regenerate environment  on my system

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me after Android Studio update and to the layout files where i was using custom components.

In Android Studio, select File > Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 1):

EditText's hint or text attributes string length should not be more than 18 chars. If u can't avoid this then use @string/mylongtext